# TypeScript separator operator behave strange

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
declare function test1<T extends unknown[]>(value: T): T
const res1 = test1([1, 2, 3]) // type is number[]


declare function test2<T extends unknown[]>(value: [...T]): T
const res2 = test2([1, 2, 3]) // type is [number,number,number]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMBGAHgBV4QAPQ1YI+NAa1RwHdUBtAXQB8ACgBuUCMhAAueJQCUMygFgAUGDwl4cIqXgBeAsTJCepADTwATBYDMfOfAD0j+KmQBbAEYgY-Vf5VQSFgEFHRsPEMSSyoaehBGZjYObn5hMQlpeB4AOjzKe0VVdVRNbUt9KIxLE3MrW3snFx43Lx8zVu8YDo8uviA)

as you can see, if I use `... separator operator` , I got totally different **result type**, and I think `[...T]` is same with `T`,because T extends  array.

is it a feature I should keep in mind and move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature, be it not a very well-documented one. If you check this [PR on Variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), the section **Spreads in array literals** contains

> The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types:

```
declare function ft1<T extends unknown[]>(t: T): T;
declare function ft2<T extends unknown[]>(t: T): readonly [...T];
declare function ft3<T extends unknown[]>(t: [...T]): T;
declare function ft4<T extends unknown[]>(t: [...T]): readonly [...T];

ft1(['hello', 42]);  // (string | number)[]
ft2(['hello', 42]);  // readonly (string | number)[]
ft3(['hello', 42]);  // [string, number]
ft4(['hello', 42]);  // readonly [string, number]
```

It allows you to pass an array as a tuple without having to add `as const` (which makes the array and its elements read-only).